# update textfield when radio button is selected and button is pressed Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button, textfield

I have 4 radio buttons, when I select one, I want the default value of the quantity(addNumberOfItems) to be 1.

when a radio button is selected it should update a textfield that holds the quantity. Afterwards I have a button to add to the order. The problem is when I click addToOrderBtn and try and increase the quantity on the textfield(I replace the default 1 with 2 or 3) it always sets it back to 1.

My textfield that keep track of Total items(totalItems), should add what I input into addNumbersOfItems.

I tried to update the value of addNumberOfItems when the button is clicked. but its still set to default value.

Javascipt only please.

Thank you!

Code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpJqgj

```
        var addNumberOfItems = document.getElementById("numberOfItems");
        var addToOrderBtn = document.getElementById("addToOrder");
        var totalItems = document.getElementById("items");
        var totalPrice = document.getElementById("total");


    if (selected == "Classic" && foodOptionChecked1 == true) {
        addNumberOfItems.value = 1;
    };


    addToOrderBtn.onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById('numberOfItems').value = addNumberOfItems.value;

        totalItems.value = addNumberOfItems.value;
        totalPrice.value = foodClassic[0].smallPrice;

        addNumberOfItems.value = "";

    };
```

HTML

```
  <fieldset class="form1 hide" id="choices">
  <legend> your Choices </legend>

   <p style="margin-left:25%">Which one would you like?</p>

  <form style="float: right" id="selectSize">

    <input type="radio" id="food1" name="size" value=""><label id="foodLabel1">food1</label> 
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="food2" name="size" value=""><label id="foodLabel2">food2</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="food3" name="size" value=""><label id="foodLabel3">food3</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="food4" name="size" value=""><label id="foodLabel4">food4</label>


     <input type="text"  id="numberOfItems" name="" value="">

   <button type="button" id="addToOrder">Add to order</button>
   <button type="button">Remove last item</button>

  </form>
  <p style="margin-top: 15%; margin-left:25%"> Extras! </p>
  <p style="margin-top: 11%; margin-left:25%"> How many? </p>

  </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="form1 hide" id="orderStatus">
      <legend> Order Status </legend>

       <form>
        Items<input type="text" name="" id="items">
        Total<input type="text" name="" id="total">

        <button type="button">Order Now</button>
        <button type="button">Cancel</button>
      </form>
     </fieldset>
```

Comment: @ShailendraSharma will do

Comment: "selected" and "foodOptionChecked1"  variables are not define what are they ?

Comment: please show your complete code or create a fiddle

Comment: @ShailendraSharma Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Socha/t16hcL8q/

Comment: there is only blank drop down with no option inside how can i reproduce your problem

Comment: @ShailendraSharma Here this code pen works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpJqgj  I appreciate  the patience. currently only the "Classic" option works with the first option "small 6 slices"

Answer (score 0):

This is because inside `getOrder()` this line addNumberOfItems.value = 1;  make quantity to 1 when you change quantity value

try following code in your getOrder() where you setting default value will solve you problem of quality reset

```
if (selected == "Classic" && foodOptionChecked1 == true) {
          if(addNumberOfItems.value.length == 0)  
             addNumberOfItems.value = 1;
            }
        };
```

but sill i am unable to find why getOrder() call after changing the quality value might be because of code in your `main.js`